# Graph, that crosses y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I draw such a graph with matplotlib?

[image: graph, that crosses y axis]

Comment: The thinng, that it should cross y axis. Offcourse I could place it there as just another line, but all the y axis numbers would still be on the side of the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/axes_grid/demo_axisline_style.html) from [this group](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/spine_placement_demo.html)

For example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def line(x, slope=1, zero=0):
    return zero + slope * x

x = np.array([-4,10])
y1 = line(x, 2, 2)
y2 = line(x, 1, 3)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y1)
ax.plot(x,y2)

ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data', 0))
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data',0))
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['left'].set_smart_bounds(True)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_smart_bounds(True)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Or closer to your picture (here I eliminated `set_smart_bounds` because in win7 seems not to have effect for the example):

```
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data', 0))
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data',0))
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
plt.ylim(ymin=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]